# Manipulate PHP array to group small values for use in Pie Chart

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I am looking for ideas on some PHP for the following -

I have an array of numerical values that feed a pie chart (created with High Charts).  These values vary in size depending what the chart is showing and the array might be up to 100 values long.

The problem is that if I send these values to the pie and a lot of the values are low, it ends up with the smaller values creating lots of pie 'slices' that are too small to read and so ineffective.  What I want to do is group all the values under a threshold % into a group called Other.

From research I can't seem to do this natively in High Charts but I think I should be able to do it with PHP.  So the PHP would have to -

1. Take an array (100, 96, 72, 25, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1) etc
2. Work out the total of the values and thus % of each -
   (33%, 32%, 23%, 8%, 1%, 0.6%, 0.3%, 0.3%, 0.3%) etc
3. Remove any values below a certain % ie 1% so that the array becomes -
   (100, 96, 72)
4. Add back into the array a value representing the total of those removed
   (100, 96, 72, 33)
5. The array can now be sent to the pie

Any ideas please?

Comment: 25 is 8%, it should remain in the result.

Comment: Do you need ideas about how to achieve this in PHP? Check the [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) section of the PHP manual. I would use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: Why not use Javascript? Also, most of the problems you outline require only rudimentary math... exactly what is it you are unable to figure out here?

Comment: @axiac in my example I wanted to filter out everything below or at 1%

Comment: @axiac I hadn't come across array_filter which seems like it will do exactly what I want - thanks

Comment: [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) can also be used (start with an empty array as the third parameter, store into it the values above the threshold, compute and store in a different variable the total of the values smaller than the threshold, put it into the returned array at the end).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I am not confident with JavaScript at the moment.  You are right that the maths are basic, it was manipulating the arrays I was unsure of.  axiac (above) pointed me to array_filter which looks like it will do want I want.

Comment: A manual traversal of the array as provided by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480018/4265352) is also possible (not as elegant as using `array_filter()` or `array_reduce()` or `array_walk()` but still effective).

Comment: @axiac. Actually there are (I see now) a whole lot of array functions I do not know.  I need to read up on these, thanks for pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$input = array(100, 96, 72, 25, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1);

$thresh = 0.01;          // Threshold; 0.01 == 1%
$extra  = 0;             // The sum of the combined slices ('Other')

// Compute the sum of all values (needed for the percentages)
$sum    = array_sum($input);
$output = array_merge(
    // Process the input list (combine and remove)
    array_filter(
        $input,
        function ($item) use ($sum, $thresh, &$extra) {
            // Compute the percentage and check it against the threshold
            if ($item / $sum < $thresh) {
                // Too small
                $extra += $item;     // Add it to 'Other'
                return FALSE;        // Remove it from the input list
            } else {
                // Above the threshold
                return TRUE;         // Let it go to the final list
            }
        }
    ),
    // Don't forget to add the combined value to the output
    array($extra)
);
```

And a solution using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$input = array(100, 96, 72, 25, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1);

$thresh = 0.01;          // Threshold; 0.01 == 1%
$extra  = 0;             // The sum of the combined slices ('Other')

// Compute the sum of all values (needed for the percentages)
$sum    = array_sum($input);
$output = array_merge(
    // Process the input list (keep, remove, combine)
    array_reduce(
        $input,
        function (array $carry, $item) use ($sum, $thresh, &$extra) {
            // Compute the percentage and check it against the threshold
            if ($item / $sum < $thresh) {
                // Too small
                $extra += $item;     // Add it to 'Other'
            } else {
                // Above the threshold
                $carry[] = $item;    // Put it into the "reduced" list
            }
            // Always return $carry (the reduced list)
            return $carry;
        },
        // Start with an empty list; here will be added the values above the threshold
        array()
    ),
    // Don't forget to add the combined value to the output
    array($extra)
);
```

Comment: Very instructive thanks.  I have it working in my application now.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$data = array(100, 96, 72, 25, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1);

// $data = array of data
// $p = percentage which any value below that 
// percentage will be removed.
function filter($data, $p) {
    $total = array_sum($data);
    $treshold = $p *  $total/ 100;
    $result = array();

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        if ($value > $treshold) $result[] = $value;
    }

    $remain = $total - array_sum($result);
    if ($remain > 0) $result[] = $remain;

    return $result;
}

// Remove any value under 1%
print_r(filter($data, 1));
```

Comment: The code works well - thanks a lot.  However, as @axiac pointed me to the array functions I will mark his answer as accepted.